# An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. No application service provider was found

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to script/export Entity Framework Core code-first migrations in Azure DevOps CI pipeline but having an error. The below command runs fine in my Visual Studio locally and generates an sql file and the command work was also working fine a few months ago in DevOps too (not sure if update related).

```
dotnet ef migrations script --project Booking.Core 
       --startup-project Booking.Management --idempotent 
       --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/migrate.sql --verbose
```

My project is using .NET Core 3.1.5 version and also in pipeline I make sure `dotnet-ef` command is available like

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 3.1.5
```

But I still keep getting this error:

```
2020-12-13T09:13:27.8973893Z ##[section]Starting: EF Core Migrations SQL Export
2020-12-13T09:13:27.9112206Z ==============================================================================
2020-12-13T09:13:27.9112480Z Task         : PowerShell
2020-12-13T09:13:27.9112737Z Description  : Run a PowerShell script on Linux, macOS, or Windows
2020-12-13T09:13:27.9112956Z Version      : 2.179.1
2020-12-13T09:13:27.9113144Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2020-12-13T09:13:27.9113446Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell
2020-12-13T09:13:27.9113759Z ==============================================================================
2020-12-13T09:13:28.8144250Z Generating script.
2020-12-13T09:13:28.8694723Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2020-12-13T09:13:28.8987598Z ##[command]"C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'D:\a\_temp\fa82967e-1e57-4dba-932d-1453e98ef510.ps1'"
2020-12-13T09:13:29.4639310Z Using project 'Booking.Core\Booking.Core.csproj'.
2020-12-13T09:13:29.4640261Z Using startup project 'Booking.Management\Booking.Management.csproj'.
2020-12-13T09:13:29.4661731Z Writing 'Booking.Core\obj\Booking.Core.csproj.EntityFrameworkCore.targets'...
2020-12-13T09:13:29.4713085Z dotnet msbuild /target:GetEFProjectMetadata /property:EFProjectMetadataFile=C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpBC2B.tmp /verbosity:quiet /nologo Booking.Core\Booking.Core.csproj
2020-12-13T09:13:30.5894726Z Writing 'Booking.Management\obj\Booking.Management.csproj.EntityFrameworkCore.targets'...
2020-12-13T09:13:30.5904170Z dotnet msbuild /target:GetEFProjectMetadata /property:EFProjectMetadataFile=C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpC091.tmp /verbosity:quiet /nologo Booking.Management\Booking.Management.csproj
2020-12-13T09:13:31.4844212Z Build started...
2020-12-13T09:13:31.4848105Z dotnet build Booking.Management\Booking.Management.csproj /verbosity:quiet /nologo
2020-12-13T09:13:39.4566730Z 
2020-12-13T09:13:39.4680169Z Build succeeded.
2020-12-13T09:13:39.4681347Z     0 Warning(s)
2020-12-13T09:13:39.4681964Z     0 Error(s)
2020-12-13T09:13:39.4682460Z 
2020-12-13T09:13:39.4683029Z Time Elapsed 00:00:07.53
2020-12-13T09:13:39.5195940Z Build succeeded.
2020-12-13T09:13:39.5465861Z dotnet exec --depsfile D:\a\1\s\Booking.Management\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Booking.Management.deps.json --additionalprobingpath C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.nuget\packages --additionalprobingpath "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder" --runtimeconfig D:\a\1\s\Booking.Management\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Booking.Management.runtimeconfig.json C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.dotnet\tools\.store\dotnet-ef\3.1.5\dotnet-ef\3.1.5\tools\netcoreapp3.1\any\tools\netcoreapp2.0\any\ef.dll migrations script --idempotent --output D:\a\1\a/migrate.sql --assembly D:\a\1\s\Booking.Management\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Booking.Core.dll --startup-assembly D:\a\1\s\Booking.Management\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Booking.Management.dll --project-dir D:\a\1\s\Booking.Core\ --language C# --working-dir D:\a\1\s --verbose --root-namespace Booking.Core
2020-12-13T09:13:39.7619178Z Using assembly 'Booking.Core'.
2020-12-13T09:13:39.7621486Z Using startup assembly 'Booking.Management'.
2020-12-13T09:13:39.7623162Z Using application base 'D:\a\1\s\Booking.Management\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1'.
2020-12-13T09:13:39.7624489Z Using working directory 'D:\a\1\s\Booking.Management'.
2020-12-13T09:13:39.7627735Z Using root namespace 'Booking.Core'.
2020-12-13T09:13:39.7628656Z Using project directory 'D:\a\1\s\Booking.Core\'.
2020-12-13T09:13:40.0447318Z Finding DbContext classes...
2020-12-13T09:13:40.0448237Z Finding IDesignTimeDbContextFactory implementations...
2020-12-13T09:13:40.1345335Z Finding application service provider...
2020-12-13T09:13:40.1352141Z Finding Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting service provider...
2020-12-13T09:13:40.1387349Z Using environment 'Development'.
2020-12-13T09:13:41.3123215Z Rollbar.RollbarException: Failed to configure using invalid configuration prototype!
2020-12-13T09:13:41.3123976Z    at Rollbar.RollbarLogger.ValidateConfiguration(IRollbarConfig rollbarConfig)
2020-12-13T09:13:41.3124504Z    at Rollbar.RollbarLogger.Configure(IRollbarConfig settings)
2020-12-13T09:13:41.3125776Z    at Rollbar.RollbarLogger.Rollbar.IRollbar.Configure(IRollbarConfig settings)
2020-12-13T09:13:41.3127983Z    at Booking.Management.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in D:\a\1\s\Booking.Management\Startup.cs:line 136
2020-12-13T09:13:41.3128521Z    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
2020-12-13T09:13:41.3129014Z    at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
2020-12-13T09:13:41.3129472Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.InvokeCore(Object instance, IServiceCollection services)
2020-12-13T09:13:41.3129921Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<Invoke>g__Startup|0(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
2020-12-13T09:13:41.3130590Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IServiceCollection services)
2020-12-13T09:13:41.3131087Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<Build>b__0(IServiceCollection services)
2020-12-13T09:13:41.3131685Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.UseStartup(Type startupType, HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services)
2020-12-13T09:13:41.3132193Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<UseStartup>b__0(HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services)
2020-12-13T09:13:41.3132570Z    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()
2020-12-13T09:13:41.3132842Z    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
2020-12-13T09:13:41.3133338Z An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: Failed to configure using invalid configuration prototype!
2020-12-13T09:13:41.3133808Z No application service provider was found.
2020-12-13T09:13:41.3309579Z Finding DbContext classes in the project...
2020-12-13T09:13:41.3402462Z Found DbContext 'ApplicationDbContext'.
2020-12-13T09:13:41.3673060Z Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationException: Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
2020-12-13T09:13:41.3674225Z  ---> System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for type 'Booking.Core.Data.ApplicationDbContext'.
2020-12-13T09:13:41.3674932Z    at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtorSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean wrapExceptions, Boolean fillCache)
2020-12-13T09:13:41.3675640Z    at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, Boolean wrapExceptions)
2020-12-13T09:13:41.3676267Z    at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic, Boolean wrapExceptions)
2020-12-13T09:13:41.3676691Z    at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
2020-12-13T09:13:41.3677358Z    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass13_3.<FindContextTypes>b__13()
2020-12-13T09:13:41.3677798Z    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2020-12-13T09:13:41.3678247Z    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass13_3.<FindContextTypes>b__13()
2020-12-13T09:13:41.3678609Z    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
2020-12-13T09:13:41.3678993Z    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
2020-12-13T09:13:41.3681847Z    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.ScriptMigration(String fromMigration, String toMigration, Boolean idempotent, String contextType)
2020-12-13T09:13:41.3682773Z    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScriptMigrationImpl(String fromMigration, String toMigration, Boolean idempotent, String contextType)
2020-12-13T09:13:41.3683262Z    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScriptMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
2020-12-13T09:13:41.3683647Z    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
2020-12-13T09:13:41.3684014Z    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
2020-12-13T09:13:41.3684531Z Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
2020-12-13T09:13:41.6277035Z ##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
2020-12-13T09:13:41.6727543Z ##[section]Finishing: EF Core Migrations SQL Export
```

My `Program.cs` file looks like this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

My `ApplicationDbContext` has constructors like:

```
protected ApplicationDbContext() {}

public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor) : base(options)
{
    _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
}
```

My `Startup.cs` file looks like:

```
public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)standard environment name (e.g: Local).
            .AddUserSecrets<Startup>()
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        Configuration = builder.Build();
        Environment = env;
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(
            config => {...})
              .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
              .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
              .AddUserValidator<IdendityUserValidator<User>>();
}
```

Comment: There is `Rollbar.RollbarException` during `ConfigureServices` which you need to investigate. With that (or any other) exception, EF Core cannot use application services to obtain `DbContext` instance, and is trying to use other ways (design time factory, parameterless constructor) which are not applicable in your case, hence the second exception.

Comment: @IvanStoev, thanks a lot for the direction. I was thinking Rollbar fails due the issue with db context. I could fix the issue now, it was just an empty access token that Rollbar was denying to accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rollbar configuration was failing because for access token it was expecting a string that was not null/empty. Since I store Rollbar access token in Azure AppService Configuration and appsettings.json did not have access token listed, error was happening. So I added access token to appsettings.json with a dummy non-empty string value. That helps Rollbar to configure itself and not fail.